# Implicit differentiation of the equation $y\sin(x+y) = 0$.

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

How can I show that $y\sin(x+y) = 0$ defines $x$ implicitly as a function of $y$ in a neighbourhood of $(0, \pi)$ and calculate its derivative $\dfrac{dx}{dy}\Bigg|_{y=\pi} ?$

I'm struggling with the implicit theorem for multivariable calculus. My attempt was:

$$\frac{d}{dy}(y\sin(x+y)) = 0$$
$$\iff \sin(x+y)\frac{d}{dy}y + y\frac{d}{dy}\sin(x+y) = 0$$
$$\iff \sin(x+y) + y\cos(x+y)\frac{d}{dy}(x+y) = 0$$
$$\iff \sin(x+y) + y\cos(x+y)\frac{d}{dy}x + y\cos(x+y) = 0$$
$$\iff \frac{dx}{dy} = -\frac{\sin(x+y) + y\cos(x+y)}{y\cos(x+y)}$$

But it doesn't seem right and neither I can calculate $\dfrac{dx}{dy}\Bigg|_{y=\pi}$ because it is still dependent on $x$. What am I doing wrong and how should I think about it?

Comment: @barrycarter The expression $\frac{d}{dy} y$ was evaluated to equal $1$.

Comment: my bad, sorry..

Comment: Your calculations are correct. Set  $ \,y=\pi, x=0$ to get $dx/dy=-1$

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to show 'implicit'-ness in a neighborhood of $(0,\pi)$, this is a hint that you need to substitute $(x,y)=(0,\pi)$ in your final expression for $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$. Your calculated expression for $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ is correct. Substituting, we have
$$\dfrac{dx}{dy}\Bigg|_{(x,y)=(0,\pi)} = -\frac{\sin(0+\pi) + \pi\cos(0+\pi)}{\pi\cos(0+\pi)} = -\frac{0-\pi}{-\pi}=-1.$$ This is the answer. Now, substituting $(x,y)=(0,\pi)$ works because your are in a neighborhood of this point in the plane.

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate dx/dy, use the "product rule" and dy/dy= 1,
d sin(x+ y)/dy= cos(x+ y)(dx/dy+ 1) giving sin(x+ y)+ ycos(x+ y)(dx/dy+ 1)= 0.
y cos(x+ y)(dx/dy+ 1)= -sin(x+ y).
dx/dy+ 1= -sin(x+ y)/(y cos(x+ y)).

dx/dy= -sin(x+ y)/(y co(x+ y))- 1.